# add a remote JS to a crossrider extension

Tags: crossrider

I am working on crossrider to make an extension that needs to add two remote JS to all pages loaded using https protocole. one script should come before  and the other one should be loaded after . I tried to follow the docs provided in crossrider website but all my attempts failed. Can you please help me to finish this. 
This is what U tried to do

```
     appAPI.ready(function($) {
     src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" />
     appAPI.dom.addRemoteJS({
     url: "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js",
     additionalAttributes: {charset: "UTF-8"},
     callback: function(ref) {
        appAPI.dom.addRemoteJS({
            url: "http://domain.com/script.js"
        });
     }
     });
     });
```

Comment: You probably want to use https URLs (ie. SSL secured) for any scripts you're trying to inject into the page. If not, some browsers will fail due to insecure content being loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the snippet is correct and conforms to the example provided in the Crossrider [docs](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.dom-method-addRemoteJS).

Upon testing your specific script URL (*that you provided elsewhere for privacy reasons*) I can see in the console that that there is an error in the second script called in the callback function, i.e. the script.js in the example snippet you provided. Once you fix this error, you can proceed to complete your extension.

[**Disclaimer**: I am a Crossrider employee]